# raw_id_fields does not show all the fields with the magnifying glass button

Tags: python, django

I have a Model with **multiple ForeignKey fields**, and I want all of these fields to be shown as a `raw_id_fields` widget, that is, with the magnifying glass button.

I tried [salmonella](https://pypi.org/project/django-salmonella/), but I get errors **in rendering of the Django Suit template.**

Tried:

```
raw_id_fields  = ('tramite', 'asignado_a', 'revisado_por', 'supervisado_por', 'marginado_por', 'recibido_por', 'digitalizada_por', 'firma', )
```

Also tried to send a list

```
raw_id_fields = ['tramite', 'asignado_a', 'revisado_por', 'supervisado_por', 'marginado_por', 'recibido_por', 'digitalizada_por', 'firma', ]
```

but nothing...

I am using Python 2.7 and Django 1.8.14

```
class PeticionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    raw_id_fields  = ('tramite', 'asignado_a', 'revisado_por', 'supervisado_por', 'marginado_por', 'recibido_por', 'digitalizada_por', 'firma', )
    list_filter = ['estado','activo']
    search_fields = ['id',]
    list_display = ('id','tramite','tipo', 'producto', 'fecha_recepcion','notaria','subtotal', 'complejidad' ,'fecha_entrega', 'fecha_vencimiento', 'estado' ,'activo')
    inlines = [ DocumentoDigitalizadoInline ]
admin.site.register(Peticion, PeticionAdmin)
```

I only wish that **all these fields with ForeignKey show the magnifying glass button and the window to associate the ForeignKey**.

Comment: Hey Edison, not an answer, but I editted your question to change it to use markup instead of `html` tags.  Markup will make your life a lot easier rather than using html tags for future questions and answers. Click the `edited x min ago` tag to look at the differences between `html` and markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until at last he finds the problem ...

It is absolutely necessary that **all the fields established in the raw_id_fields have their own ModelAdmin associated**, encoded in Admin.py.

The problem was that the fields
`('assigned_a', 'revised_by', 'supervised_by', 'marginalized_by', 'received_by', 'digitized_by', 'signed',)`

they belonged to a **class "Person"** but this **was not associated to a ModelAdmin** as the class `PeticionAdmin`; that is, you must define `"PersonaAdmin"` so that the magnifying glass appears and I can search this field.

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the trouble to answer your question, @Edison Aviles Munoz. This is just what I needed. +1 +1